# Team Build doesn't create the bin folder and the linked assembly

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I want to use TFS Team Build, and have created a build definition. The trigger is gated check-in.

When I check in the code, the build fails and I face the following error:

> C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (177): Unable to copy file "bin\OTS.RMS.DomainModel.dll" to "C:\Builds\1\OTC-RMS\Main Build\Binaries_PublishedWebsites\WebUIController\bin\OTS.RMS.DomainModel.dll". Could not find file 'bin\OTS.RMS.DomainModel.dll'.

Some information regarding the project:

1. OTS.RMS.DomainModel.dll is a class library that has my business logic code
2. WebUIController is an MVC project
3. I use Visual studio 2010 and TFS 2010

I've tried many solutions. One was to check-in the bin folder with its DLLs into source control. When I do that, the build succeeds, but I shouldn't do that because for each build there is a conflict between my local DLLs and the server DLLs. By default, the bin and the generated DLLs should stay out of TFS.

After investigation on the TFS machine, I found the builds folder in the C: drive which will be used as a source folder. Team Build can get the source from the check-in and put this files inside this folder to start build it.

I don't know why Team Build didn't create the bin folder and the DLLs as a result for the build and start copying the DLLs to the binary folder as needed.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: What version of TFS are you using (2005, 2008 or 2010)?

Comment: You may not noticed the version but I already mention that, I use TFS 2010, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fault as I was looking in the wrong directory